# Debounce mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I'm building a custom jQuery code to allow the user to be guided through a webpage by using the mousewheel.

The code I'm building is simulair to this page: [Link](http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/)

Everything works fine, but the mousewheel event fires multiple times by default, making the script 'skip' complete divs and scroll down/up multiple times, instead of just once.

I need a way to limit the mousewheel to fire only once. In my quest of finding the answer I found Ben Alman's script wich uses 'debounce'.

My question here is; is there a way to debounce EVERY mousewheel event instead of debouncing it's function? So basicly telling 'mouse wheel' to fire once every 500ms, and ignore all fires that were send in that 500ms period.

Comment: use a timeout to debounce it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `setTimeout` to control the firing of events - as:

```
$("div").html((new Array(1000)).join(" test")).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll", function()
{
    if (!$(this).data('flag'))
    {
        var self = this;
        $(this).data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            $(self).data('flag', false);
        }, 500));

        $(this).data('flag', true);

        console.log('here');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aN4hU/

Comment: The functionality is exactly what I'm looking for, trying it out right away. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if that makes any difference, but if you need your script to behave like on that website, I'd use `animate` function and base the logic on that - as you want the scrolling to be possible when the animation has finished (and not when 500ms has elapsed - taking into account different screen resolutions, the animation durations will take different amounts of time to finish).

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed this problem after implementing your code snippet. However, I need the divs to 'snap' on windowresize.      $(window).resize(function () $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);}); 

Wich wouldn't be possible with animations.

Comment: Hmm - I don't know about impossible, but I'd do it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aN4hU/1/. Now - there's still an instance of scroll event to be taken care of, as: check which slide is visible, and scroll to it.