# Why does my jquery take so long when animating on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a box that slides right 100px when you scroll 10px and slide back to it's default location if the scroll is less than 10px. The box does animate, however, there is a bit of a delay when it does. Can anyone help me figure this out?

HTML

```
<div id="nest">
  <div id="box">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nest {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 150px
}

#box {
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: green;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    jQuery('#box').animate({left:'100px'})


  } else {
    jQuery('#box').animate({left:'0px'})
}
});
```

My JSFIDDLE LINK
https://jsfiddle.net/ispykenny/m6ffj83g/1/

thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: `.scrollTop()` sets the scrollTop. To get it, use `.scrollTop` without parentheses

Comment: Because scroll event handler is fired many times and each time it put a new animation in queue. Debouncing scroll event using a timeout could be  a workaround or dequeue fx queue   https://jsfiddle.net/m6ffj83g/2/

Comment: Try and add a set timeout on the scroll event, otherwise it checks for every 1px scroll

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: This is a perfect scenario for debounce: debouncing can be as simple as setTimeout/clearTimeout.   Here's a similar question using a flag (rather than clearTimeout) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141933/debounce-mouse-wheel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your animation is taking so long would be that the animate is running on every scroll event past 10px, and this is quite intensive on the client-side. There are a few options, either experiment with the .stop() functionality in jQuery, or write a a conditional if statement that checks if the animation will have started and only fires if it hasn't.

https://api.jquery.com/stop/

this is a handy resource.

```
var coin = false;

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 10 && coin === false) {
    jQuery('#box').animate({left:'100px'});
    coin = true;
  } else if (coin === true && jQuery(this).scrollTop() <= 10) {
    jQuery('#box').animate({left:'0px'});
    coin = false;
}
});
```

try this!

Comment: And every animate() call lasts 400 ms by default.